# Populate a select with all the countries using ajax/php/api

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl

I want to populate a select dropdown with all the countries from the rest countries api. I want to do so using an ajax call to a php routine that makes an http request with curl to the api, which retrieves the country names.

I have seen most people do it using fetch().

If anyone knows how to do it using ajax and php, your help is much appreciated!

I do not know how to implement this so anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request in ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.com',
  data: data, //arguments
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data){
     return data;
  }, // if success
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

In success, you can set the value of a var the result of request, or you can return the value if is in a scope of a function.
And the select you can make in php like this:

```
<select name="select">
    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value['value']; ?>"><?php echo $value['text']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```